# Android getAllCellInfo() returning unknown cells

Tags: java, android, react-native, mobile

I'm using the `getAllCellInfo()` method in Android as part of a React Native app to try to get information about cell strength for different network operators.

The method is returning a number of LTE cells, but only the registered one has actual values for MCC and MNC when I get the cells' identities. All other cell identity methods return null except `getPci()` and `getEarfcn()` which seem to be correct.

My code looks like this:

```java
@ReactMethod
public void getAllCarriers(Callback successCallback) {
    List<CellInfo> allCellInfo = this.telephony.getAllCellInfo();
    WritableArray preparedInfo = Arguments.createArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < allCellInfo.size(); i++) {
        CellInfo info = allCellInfo.get(i);
        WritableMap extractedInfo = Arguments.createMap();

        String mcc = "";
        String mnc = "";

        if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
            CellIdentityGsm identity = ((CellInfoGsm)info).getCellIdentity();
            mcc = identity.getMccString();
            mnc = identity.getMncString();
        }
        else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
            CellIdentityLte identity = ((CellInfoLte)info).getCellIdentity();
            mcc = identity.getMccString();
            mnc = identity.getMncString();
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }

        extractedInfo.putString("mcc", mcc);
        extractedInfo.putString("mnc", mnc);

        preparedInfo.pushMap(extractedInfo);
    }

    successCallback.invoke(preparedInfo, allCellInfo.size());
}
```

Is this just a limitation of the technology or am I doing something wrong?

For some extra information, the Phone I've been getting these results on is a Xiaomi POCOPHONE F1 running Android 10.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like this may be an issue to do with the OS, as the results are different when running the app on a Samsung phone.